# R error : lazy load database, splines.rdb is corrupt

Tags: r

I updated R a few weeks ago (4.1.0) and everything was fine but today I noticed that a number of my packages were just missing. On the packages window is just says "[Failed to read package metadata]" and when I try to load them they are missing. Fine, I'll just reinstall. Then I start to get a rash of other errors. There's too many to list them all, but the most recurrent ones are:

- "Error in readRDS(file) : error reading from connection" repeated about 50 times when I try to download a package.
- "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘lme4’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
  lazy-load database '.../R/R-41~1.0/library/splines/R/splines.rdb' is corrupt" whenever I try to load certain packages
- "could not find function _____" when the associated package is installed and loaded.
- "In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1" when failing to load packages

I've tried restarting R and my computer, replacing the splines.rdb' file, updating packages, all to no avail. I've reinstalled every missing package I can find in the hopes of hitting the one that's causing the problems, but no dice. I've read elsewhere that it might be an issue with my version of Java, but I can't understand why the problem wouldn't have appeared right after I updated R (also, it being a work computer I will need an IT person to install that for me, which could take a while).

What might have gone wrong?

Comment: Why would you update to 4.1.0?  That was released in May, 2021.  But in any case, you've somehow got a corrupted install, so wipe out all of it (including the library of packages), and install either the current version (4.2.2) or at least the most-fixed version of the 4.1.x series, i.e. 4.1.3.

Comment: huh, that's odd, I thought I was getting the most up-to-date. I was hoping to avoid a total re-install, but I guess that's what it'll come to.  Thanks.

Comment: update: turns out I had both 4.1.0 and 4.2.2 installed at the same time. Got rid of the older version and everything is (seemingly) working fine now.